# Definir um discador como padrão

Tags: android

eu já tenho um app simples que apenas faz a ligação a partir do momento que clica em um botão  que realiza a chamada,
 eu quero tornar este app como padrão no Dialer para que toda vez que eu clique no botão  "Call" padrão do telefone  ele abra meu app, 
ou seja; torna-lo padrão dentro dele.

- estou usando a api 23
- dentro do Configurações/app/configurações padrões  meu app não aparece

minha dúvida é como faço para ele aparecer ali  ? que código eu coloco ?

não consegui achar nada sobre isso, gostaria de uma ajuda, obrigado..

Answer (score 1):

Vá em Configurações -> Aplicativos -> Gerenciar Aplicativos.

Selecione a guia "Todos" e vá até o aplicativo de discagem atual.

Procure o botão "Limpar predefinições" e aperte. Agora, quando você seleciona discagem, você deve ser solicitado a selecionar um aplicativo específico e também ter a oportunidade de definir um novo padrão.